# C# List<LinkButton> Collection cssclass not getting applied

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections

I've couple of LinkButtons for which I want to manipulate the cssclass property.

Earlier I used each LinkButton individually to change the cssclass and it worked perfectly upon postback. E.g. `lnkbtnHome.CssClass = "tab";`

But over time the items increased so I thought it could be better way to do it and I decided to use the Listcollection and use `foreach` loop to do the same.
Below is the code that I'm using currently.

By default (upon page load) the first button is having a different class `tabsel` and I want to reset the class of all buttons by setting the class to `tab`. Upon debugging I can see the cssclass getting modified but it's not changing up in the browser.

Am I missing something?

**Under Declaration:**

```
static List<LinkButton> lnklist;
```

**Under PageLoad:**

```
lnklist = new List<LinkButton>();
lnklist.Add(lnkbtnHome);
lnklist.Add(lnkbtnSubject);
lnklist.Add(lnkbtnReport);
```

**Upon Postback:**

```
foreach (var lnkbtn in lnklist){
    lnkbtn.CssClass = "tab";
}
```

Comment: "Upon debugging I can see the cssclass getting modified but it's not working." Can you explain this further?  It seems contradictory.  How can it work and not work at the same time?

Comment: Never use `static` fields in ASP.NET.

Comment: @Brian Updated the question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I used static to avoid losing the items upon postback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Never* use static fields in ASP.NET!

You:

> I used static to avoid losing the items upon postback.

but that's the nature of HTTP. It's a stateless protocol. You should recreate all controls on each postback in the same way as ASP.NET does it. Otherwise you're are vulnerable to various issues since ASP.NET is a multithreading environment. You *could* store it in the `Session`, but i would advise against it. `LinkButton` is a webcontrol which needs to be part of the current page's control collection. This page will be destroyed at the end of it's lifecycle.